# CKEDITOR inline content getting deleted from database (but only occassionally!)

Tags: php, ckeditor

I cannot figure out why my ckeditor inline content is being deleted from my MYSQL database. To make things more confusing, it is being deleted extremely randomly...once a week, for example.  Also, not ALL inline editable areas from the 10 or so pages on my site are being deleted, this is also random. Here is an example of the code I use to populate my inline content areas.  I have found nothing at all on this issue so I am starting to think it is something that I have done wrong.

```
<div id="content"><div class="content">
        <div id="colLt" class="clearfix">
            <?php include('tabContent.php');?>
            <?php include('leftSidebar.php');?>
        </div>
        <div id="colRt"><div class="content">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <?php
        if ($_SESSION['auth']==1){
            echo "<div id='pracDev' contenteditable='true' onblur='savePracDevContent()'>";
        } else {
            echo "<div id='pracDev'>";
        }
        connect();
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contentAreas") or die("nothing found");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        echo $row['pracDevContent'];?>
        </div><!--end training-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function savePracDevContent() {
                var data = CKEDITOR.instances.pracDev.getData();
                $.post('savePracDevContent.php', {pracDevContent : data})       
            }
        </script>
</div></div>
```

By the way, I am successful at editing and saving data with all my inline editable areas. My only issue is that occassionally, my content is deleted from the database.  Could it be the method in which the hosting company is backing up the data?  Thanks for any thoughts...

Comment: You have provided us with almost zero backend code. Could you tell more about code that is in charge for deleting/editing content from database?

Comment: There is no code for deleting/editing content. That's the beauty of the inline editor.  One just clicks inside of the designated div...the editor pops up if ($_SESSION['auth']==1)...and one can delete/edit content at this time.  No separate module for deleting/editing content is necessary.